# Fix Background not consistent on Vite React App on mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, vite

So the desktop version of my react app is working and running perfectly fine.
https://sabateesh.dev/
However the problem im facing is the mobile version of the react-app
See here [Chrome Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc0yy.png)

How do i fix this?
code is found at https://github.com/Sabateesh/reactapp

I've tried updating my browsers on mobile.